# How to infer schema from type with Yup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, formik, yup

Is it possible to infer Yup schema from a Type? I know Yup can infer a TypeScript type alias using the exported `InferType` but I want exactly the opposite, this is from a Type get a valid schema.

*Note:
I'm aiming for something like this because currently I have a very large and complex Yup schema (for formik validationSchema) which is a union of other (already defined) types (generated by graphql codegen).*

Comment: Moving from a type to a value (and the yup schema is a JS value) is in principle impossible. Information can flow from values to types never the other way around as types are erased during compilation, so you can't really have a value get any info from a type at runtime. You could use the compiler api, to extract info the type and then generate the schema as part of your build process.

Comment: https://medium.com/@maurice.de.beijer/yup-validation-and-typescript-and-formik-6c342578a20e